# Share Facebook insights for all my company without needing to setup individual accounts

Tags: facebook, facebook-insights

We have a page at something like `facebook.com/%companyname%/page_insights` but only the users who were given explicit access at the company page’s admin panel can view it.

And we all have `@companyname.com` kind of email address and if I need to add 20 accounts as "insight analystis" to people who would then need to create a new facebook account, well, that's just *not going to happen*. So...

Is there any **simple way** to make it visible to everyone at our company?

Couple of things I am thinking of, out of the box:

- maybe there is a public unpublished link — like many photo albums on the web do
- or I'd create a "shared account" with restricted access — in which people would login with a shared password but are unable to change the password or any account setting.

Answer (score 1):

There is not way to add more than one Admin Manager at a time to a Facebook Page.

You can have unlimited Admin managers for any of 5 Admin roles; however, each Admin must have a Facebook personal profile and be added 'one-by-one.'

You would likely choose "Insights Analyst" [view Insights only] for general employee population adds.

Comment: Not planning to add more admin managers at all, and you sound pretty contradicting to yourself there. "no way to add more than one" vs "unlimited". In any case I think can better formulate my question now.

Comment: ... "no way to add more than one *at a time*".  No contradiction.